# AJAX request to Laravel backend returns 419 CSRF token mismatch

Tags: ajax, laravel, csrf, laravel-sanctum

I'm creating a SPA using NextJS and I have a Laravel backend for my API. To authenticate my SPA I'm using laravel sanctum.

My API is on api.domain.com and my app is on domain.com

I've set these environment variables which are relevant to this issue:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain.com
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="domain.com"
```

When I log in I make a request to `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` to get my CSRF cookie, and I can see in my following requests I am sending the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header with the value from the cookie.

I'm wondering if anyone else has had a similar issue with CSRF mismatches when using sanctum on different subdomains?

Answer (score 0):

OK what ended up fixing my issue is changing the name of my session cookie to something without an underscore, very weird!